# Explain the reason for such output of this C program

Tags: c

Please help me to understand the output of the following C program.

```
#include "stdio.h"
int fun(int x)
{
    static int a=0;
    return x+a++;
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;++i)
    printf("%d ",fun(printf("%d",0)));
    return 0;
}
```

output is : 01 02 03 04 05

why not : 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: You realise that your function makes 10 calls to `printf` right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `0` is the result of the execution of the `printf()` statement inside the `fun()` function call

```
fun(printf("%d",0))
```

and the second `1` is the result of the outer `printf()` which prints the return value of the `fun()` function call. The `fun()` function call sends the return value of the inner `printf()` which is always `1`, and since you have initialized the variable `a` as `static` the value of `a` remains same and is added everytime with the function call.

since you are always printing `0` in the `printf()` inside the `fun()` function call, hence the `0` before the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The arguments are evaluated in order when you call `printf` here:

```
printf("%d ",fun(printf("%d",0)));
```

The outer `printf` call needs to evaluate all its arguments, which is the following:

```
fun(printf("%d",0))
```

Which then calls the inner `printf` to evaluate all of its arguments.

First, `printf("%d",0)` will be evaluated, and evaluate to the number of characters printed (since this is what `printf()` returns). This is passed to `fun` next, which will return the number of characters the `printf` printed (1) plus the number of times it has been called (due to the `static int a`). That will then be passed to the outer printf, printing the second number, then a space.

Comment: "evaluated in order". Which order do you mean? You mean inner to outer right?

Comment: There is one specific point that I think we should draw attention to in this question. The inner workings of the `fun` function use post-increment, not pre-increment. That could be confusing for anyone who is not overly familiar with the code. Since `printf("%d", 0) == 1` it will always be called as `fun(1)`, which results in the output described in the result.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that in this statement

```
printf("%d ",fun(printf("%d",0)));
```

function `printf` is called twice. At first it is called as the argument expression of function `fun`

```
fun(printf("%d",0))
```

and outputs aways 0.

The second time the function is called with the resut of the call of function `fun` Take into account that the value of call

```
printf("%d",0)
```

is always equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

imagine your commands in the way that it is evaluated:

```
printf("%d ",fun(printf("%d",0)));
```

is equivalent to:

```
int printf_result = printf("%d",0);
int fun_result = fun(printf_result);
printf(("%d ",fun_result);
```

this is c. this is not python or matlab. if you assign the result value it doesn't influence the effects of the function call.